# Azure AD B2C - risks of sharing app Client Id

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am building an Angular SPA app and plan to open source via a public GitHub repo. The app will leverage Azure AD B2C for authentication. What risks am I exposed to if I share the B2C data points (Client Id, Tenant, scopes, policy names)? Is it an acceptable security practice to include these config options with the code or should I move the values to another storage mechanism and out of the source code?

Thinking on my own, the biggest risk seems to be that others could clone the app and run it locally (ie. their own machine) against my B2C instance. Not sure if that's really a big deal - perhaps it's a benefit since this is an open source app.

Answer (score 3):

**None**, assuming your app will be hosted on the internet.  That information will all be publicly exposed anyways as the Angular code needs to know those values to properly send the user to B2C (via redirects or popups).

> Is it an acceptable security practice to include these config options with the code or should I move the values to another storage mechanism and out of the source code?

Even if you moved those values out of the Angular code, you would have to make a rest call to get this info and therefore would be exposing it.

Also, all of the information is in the URL when the user is on the B2C site.

---

> ... the biggest risk seems to be that others could clone the app and run it locally (ie. their own machine) against my B2C instance...

Not likely as the **reply url** will prevent this*.  **This is the key** to the values you mentioned being exposed.

From the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com):

> Redirect URIs must all belong to the same domain

Since you control setting the reply url(s) in the Azure Portal, you prevent malicious sites from doing harm.

- There is one exception; you can have a value of localhost and a single domain.

  - https://localhost:44300
  - https://jwt.ms

---

Unfortunately there is not a good official example of a SPA demo using B2C but we can still review the [WingTip Games demo](https://wingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net/) (it uses Auth code flow, not implicit flow)

See this [sign-in link](https://login.microsoftonline.com/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=b2c_1a_sign_up_sign_in_games&client_id=f327751f-477c-4df8-a174-f59786d99d9f&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net%2Fb2c_1a_sign_up_sign_in_games-callback&response_type=code%20id_token%20token&scope=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fb2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwingtipb2c%2FBilling.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fb2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwingtipb2c%2FMusic.Read&response_mode=form_post&nonce=636594339812232723.ZmYwMjYwMTQtYWUwNy00ZjdiLTgzM2YtYTdmYzk5NmJjZTY5ODg3NTdjMTAtYTVlZC00MDc2LWE5YjktYmY2ZmE5YzU1MjMw&client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer&client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJicmFuZCI6IldpbmdUaXAgR2FtZXMiLCJwbGF5ZXJfcHJvZmlsZV9yZWdpc3RyYXRpb25fbW9kZSI6IkZ1bGwiLCJuYmYiOjE1MjM4MzcxODEsImV4cCI6MTUyMzgzNzQ4MSwiaWF0IjoxNTIzODM3MTgxLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2xvZ2luLm1pY3Jvc29mdG9ubGluZS5jb20vZWMwZTI5NzItMzQwMy00Njg1LTk4M2EtN2MwYjhmYmY3Zjg2L3YyLjAvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly93aW5ndGlwZ2FtZXNiMmMuYXp1cmV3ZWJzaXRlcy5uZXQvYjJjXzFhX3NpZ25fdXBfc2lnbl9pbl9nYW1lcy1jYWxsYmFjayJ9.4itB_MszC-gUURLe2S-ccgZeUl_T7AH3OlM2ZSzkBKw&state=CfDJ8FJ-0iVslDdJl99XvGePF_FeH6fCFEkMp4g1rO7U40L-kCZh0xuJkzljSuGt2LlwG0PW0YSw4vVMeNTFNbpaDCPoaGQLNJgsbs6mJMypy1fkE6M6KBNL_BOqHhfzKqAJJkiZlaft4KrYJ7dtJjhN8IpRCv6WVB-YYjCaVLpDNW1Zze8Sh7skbTOTBrtJo3b1aSsI3NP3x3IjDa28IGkNLQUrWRXTtGy62Y7jogj21mEhyek-Oqh8dO_1SuJwcv0C0YGq1j_6q94KgYIVOTx3De7dIJe9ac0WYWqMnRhxKKfHWm67bzChd7UAyAJf3qSVgif67KpTCSo4BftIeioUHlueK6jHSdcbqAjSlQKCFzyGJ3pAdBQI8xjmCyo9xPFNA0x4oqPHwpQmuQw0gMWOzX8).  We can see the following in the URL

- Then **tenant** is in the url (b2ctechready): https://login.microsoftonline.com/b2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize
- **p**=b2c_1a_sign_up_sign_in_games (this is the B2C policy)
- **client_id**=f327751f-477c-4df8-a174-f59786d99d9f
- **redirect_uri**=https%3A%2F%2Fwingtipgamesb2c.azurewebsites.net%2Fb2c_1a_sign_up_sign_in_games-callback
- response_type=code%20id_token%20token
- **scope**=openid%20profile%20https%3A%2F%2Fb2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwingtipb2c%2FBilling.Read%20https%3A%2F%2Fb2ctechready.onmicrosoft.com%2Fwingtipb2c%2FMusic.Read
- response_mode=form_post
- nonce=636594241776916748.Y2FmOGUxYmEtZWQ4ZS00YjAxLWJkZDQtNTMwOGNjMGRhNGI0ZGE0YjU4YjItZDljNS00MDcwLWJhMTgtMmIzMjdhY2MwZjZk
- client_assertion_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Aclient-assertion-type%3Ajwt-bearer
- client_assertion=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.ey...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is any more risky than you publishing the Angular client and others viewing the page source.

Having said that, I believe it is a better developer experience if you insert placeholders in the published source, so developers can replace them with their own values.